# How to choose the appropriate decorator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-decorator

I creating a game that use a AI. This AI'API has to 3 methods written in an Angular Service

Here's a the simplified code:

```
app.service('AI', [function(){
   return {
     offer: angular.noop,
     accept: angular.noop,
     reject: angular.noop
   }
}])
```

The difficult part is that the methods implementation (and so, how AI react) can change according to several parameters (nationality, age etc...).

I thought about use angular Decorator but I will need to choose between several decorator.
I can create files/implementations:

- less-than-10.decorator.js
- less-than-20.decorator.js
- etc...

but how can I say:

"I have a 18 years old player... load less-than-20.decorator.js and apply decorator"

OR

"I have a 18 years old player... use this decorator instead of this one"

**To resume**: I want to do a conditional decorator (loading).

After some search I found a way to do this: Instead of return $delegate I can return the original service but I think it's not a pretty way...

Have you got a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a factory instead of a service?

```
// teenagerAI and adultAI could be values, constants, factories...
app.factory('createAI', function (teenagerAI, adultAI) {
   return function (aiType) {
       switch (aiType) {
       case 'teenager':
           return teenagerAI;
       case 'adult':
           return adultAI;
       }
   };
});
```

Then you can inject `createAI` and use it:

```
createAI('adult');
```

Comment: I thought about it but as I will probably twenty or more different AI, add twenty+ denpencies is not the best way...

Comment: You may consider using `$injector.get(foo);` in your factory.

Comment: Finally used a factory  + $injector.get(foo);.Thks.